# Отражение источника света на зеркальной поверхности. Unity3D

Tags: unity3d

Есть источник света Direction Light и есть зеркальная поверхность. На зеркальной поверхности отражается источник света в виде белого пятна. Вопрос: что можно сделать, чтобы освещение оставалось таким же, как и было, но источника света не было бы видно на зеркальной поверхности в виде белого пятна?